# Send a message if Wait_For_Message timeout is reached Discord Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to send a message if the timeout is reached for client.wait_for_message. In this case it's 30 seconds. I used TimeoutError but it doesn't throw any errors or work.

```
 try:
    msg = await client.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=message.author, check=check)
        if msg:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Nice job! {} solved the scramble! The word was {}!".format(message.author.mention, word))
    except TimeoutError:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Oops! Nobody solved it. The word was {}!".format(word))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry after researching a bit I came up with this solution:

```py
msg = await client.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=message.author, check=check)
if msg:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Nice job! {} solved the scramble! The word was {}!".format(message.author.mention, word))
elif msg is None:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Oops! Nobody solved it. The word was {}!".format(word))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import asyncio

try:
    msg = await client.wait_for_message(timeout= 30, author=message.author, check=check)
    if msg:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "message")
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "message")
```

Your indentation was wrong and your statement for except as well
It should be asyncio.TimeoutError

Sorry for replying on a 2 y/o post

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how your answer is different to the old and accepted one. And if you think the indentation is wrong, you can `edit` the old answer. I think this would be even better instead of copy and past the old one.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. But I suggested to use the `edit` link right below of the answer of @hardestchat. What you did is copy'n'past and creating a new answer which is nearly identical to the old one.

Comment: oh sorry, im fairly new to stack overflow

Comment: That's ok. I am only responding to explain this to you. And don't be afraid, mistakes can happen. It's good that you are participating and you are welcome on SO.