# What's a method for catching and responding to timeouts from discord.py wait_for_messages?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

In my discord bot, I'm working on a command where you can do something like !command, then the bot replies with "Execute command? [y/n]" and listens for you saying "y", and doing something. I'm trying to add a timeout to this function, but I can't catch when this timeout happens and trigger an event, such as when the timeout happens, the bot says "Confirmation timed out." and continues.

I've already tried `elif userinput is None:` and `elif userinput is '':`, both of which didn't trigger.
I'm using discord.py 0.16.12 with Python 3.6.1, on Raspbian stretch.

This is what I currently have:

```
msgconfirm = await client.say(f"[{context.message.author.mention}] Confirm? [y/n]")
userinput = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=5, author=context.message.author)
if userinput.clean_content.lower() == 'y':
    do something
elif userinput is None:
    do something
else:
    do something
```

Currently, when the timeout triggers, it just ignores the next message I send, but doesn't trigger the `elif userinput is None:`. I'm looking for it to trigger that block, so I can add something like `await client.say(f"[{context.message.author.mention}] Confirmation timed out.`

I've already tried using the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360859/send-a-message-if-wait-for-message-timeout-is-reached-discord-py) page, though none of them work. The code on that page isn't formatted properly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of moving things around, I found out that if you just put the ``` if userinput == None:`` at the top of the if section, and move the ```if userinput,clean_content.lower() == 'y':` to the current elif line, everything works fine. Working example:

```
if userinput is None:
    do something
elif userinput.clean_content.lower() == 'y':
    do something
else:
    do something
```